# Rails: undefined method `%' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I am having a problem with rails: i'm trying to do an app for password management for personal use and for learning rails and I want the passwords to be encrypted (for now i'm using blowfish algorithm).  I've installed the crypt gem and written some code, but i am receiving a strange error.

Here's my code:

app/controller/credentials_controller.rb (scaffolded generate)

```
def create
  @credential = current_user.credentials.build(params[:credential])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @credential.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@credential, :notice => 'Credential was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @credential, :status => :created, :location => @credential }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @credential.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/credential.rb (in the db i've created a salt:string column)

```
require 'crypt/blowfish'                           

 class Credential < ActiveRecord::Base  
    before_save :hash_password
    before_update :hash_password
    after_find :unhash_password

    private
    def hash_password
      self.salt = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(8)
      blowfish = Crypt::Blowfish.new(self.salt)
      self.pass = blowfish.encrypt_block(self.pass)
    end

    def unhash_password
    end
end
```

app/views/credential/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@credential) do |f| %>
 <% if @credential.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@credential.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this credential from being saved:</h2>

   <ul>
   <% @credential.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
   </ul >
 </div> 
   <% end %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :servizio %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :servizio %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :url %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :url %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :utente %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :utente %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :pass %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :pass %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :note %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :note %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">

<%= collection_select(:credential, :group_id, current_user.groups, :id, :nome,  prompt => 'Seleziona Gruppo') %>    
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the error is:

```
`Action Controller: Exception caught
NoMethodError in CredentialsController#create 
 undefined method '%' for true:TrueClass
app/models/credential.rb:17:in 'hash_password'
app/controllers/credentials_controller.rb:47
app/controllers/credentials_controller.rb:46:in 'create'
```

---

note: if in credential model

```
def hash_password
    self.salt = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(8)
    plainBlock = "ABCD1234"
    blowfish = Crypt::Blowfish.new(self.salt)
    self.pass = blowfish.encrypt_block(plainBlock)
  end
```

it works, but the password (obviously) is always ABCD1234. the code above, mean that the problem is self.pass in blowfish.encrypt_block function.

What am I doing wrong?

If I skip the before_save function it works as a non-encrypted password, so i exclude routes-related problems.

thank you very much!

best regards!

ps: i'm using Rails 3.0.8
ps: i'm following this page http://crypt.rubyforge.org/blowfish.html

Comment: Looks like the problem is actually happening in code you are not including above.  What is in your 'hash_password' function in the Credential model?  You should edit your post to include it.

Comment: thank you very much ipd. now the code is correct.

Comment: uh, sure, what was the problem?

Comment: mu, i've added some information to the post. salt is a random string generated by `self.salt = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(8)`, and pass is defined by the user from the view. thanks.

Comment: @ipd: the problem persist, i've UPDATED the post. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the solution. the problems was:

```
self.salt = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(8)
```

in this case, self.salt has to be 56 bytes length, because blowfish require a 56byte key.

```
self.pass = blowfish.encrypt_block(self.pass)
```

in blofwish, self.pass has to be 8 bytes length

best regards and thanks for your support

Comment: I ran into this problem -- the password has to be *AT LEAST* 8 characters in length.  The appropriate way we dealt with this was to pad all input with 8 known characters at the end, and then on the decrypt we would do the opposite (to allow PWs of less than 8 characters).